# How to ensure that Shiny App Checkboxes are updated correctly?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

currently go the following situation:

For example - Run the App - Press the button Reset all Checkboxes - Now see the following behaviour -

On the "edibles" tab "check" the box titled "bacon", now switch tabs and go on the "Fried" tab and "check" the "Select All" button

this removes the "checked" bacon checkbox we originally checked and uses the "Fried" tab as essentially the first instance of pressing anything -

sure you can check whatever you want afterwards including pressing select all again or other checkboxes and removing some, but this behaviour is buggy because of that first Dplyr statement as it uses it like a "first case" type of situation even though its in an observe

Code is found below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel"),
    tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
           tabPanel("Visualisation",
                    br(),
                    width = 12, 
                    height = 800
           )
    ),
    column(12, actionButton(inputId ="resetBtn", label = "Reset Selection", icon = icon("times-circle")))
  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Gym_type = as.character(paste("Gym", 1:15)), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
            food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

            tabPanel(food[i], 
                     checkboxGroupInput(paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                        label = NULL, 
                                        choices = nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
                                          filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
                                          select(Product_name) %>%
                                          unlist(use.names = FALSE)),
                     checkboxInput(paste0("chksingle_all_", i), "Select all", value = TRUE)
            )
          })))

      ) # end of Tab box



      # When selecting by the strength of links connected to the issues:  
    } else if(input$select_by == "Gym") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("chkgrp_select_gyms", "Select gyms you want to display", choices = unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Gym_type)
                             ,
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    } else if(input$select_by == "TV") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("chkgrp_select_tvs", 
                             "Select the tv shows you want to see",choices = sort(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$TV)),
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    }  # end of else if

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))
      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("chksingle_all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("chksingle_all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices = product_choices,
                                   selected = product_choices)
        } else {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices =product_choices)
        }
      }
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$resetBtn, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    resetChksingleInputs <- names(input)[grepl("^chksingle*", names(input))]
    cat("Resetting single checkboxes:", resetChksingleInputs, sep = "\n")
    lapply(resetChksingleInputs, updateCheckboxInput, session=session, value = FALSE)

    resetChkgrpInputs <- names(input)[grepl("^chkgrp*", names(input))]
    cat("Resetting checkbox groups:", resetChkgrpInputs, sep = "\n")
    lapply(resetChkgrpInputs, updateCheckboxGroupInput , session=session, selected = character(0))

  })

} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the logic of your observer to update the checkboxGroupInputs.
Everytime **one** of the 'select all'-boxes is checked **every** other 'select all'-box will be re-evaluated - If they are deselected also the checkboxGroupInputs will be deselected.

You can see, that the selection isn't dropped when you disregard your else-statement inside the observer:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel"),
    tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
           tabPanel("Visualisation",
                    br(),
                    width = 12, 
                    height = 800
           )
    ),
    column(12, actionButton(inputId ="resetBtn", label = "Reset Selection", icon = icon("times-circle")))
  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Gym_type = as.character(paste("Gym", 1:15)), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
            food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

            tabPanel(food[i], 
                     checkboxGroupInput(paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                        label = NULL, 
                                        choices = nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
                                          filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
                                          select(Product_name) %>%
                                          unlist(use.names = FALSE)),
                     checkboxInput(paste0("chksingle_all_", i), "Select all", value = TRUE)
            )
          })))

      ) # end of Tab box



      # When selecting by the strength of links connected to the issues:  
    } else if(input$select_by == "Gym") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("chkgrp_select_gyms", "Select gyms you want to display", choices = unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Gym_type)
                             ,
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    } else if(input$select_by == "TV") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("chkgrp_select_tvs", 
                             "Select the tv shows you want to see", choices = sort(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$TV)),
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    }  # end of else if

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))
      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("chksingle_all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("chksingle_all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices = product_choices,
                                   selected = product_choices)
        }
      }
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$resetBtn, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    resetChksingleInputs <- names(input)[grepl("^chksingle*", names(input))]
    cat("Resetting single checkboxes:", resetChksingleInputs, sep = "\n")
    lapply(resetChksingleInputs, updateCheckboxInput, session=session, value = FALSE)

    resetChkgrpInputs <- names(input)[grepl("^chkgrp*", names(input))]
    cat("Resetting checkbox groups:", resetChkgrpInputs, sep = "\n")
    lapply(resetChkgrpInputs, updateCheckboxGroupInput , session=session, selected = character(0))

  })

} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Nevertheless, this way your `checkboxGroupInput`s won't follow if your "all"-`checkboxInput` is deselected. To also allow the deselection via "all", without dropping selections in the other tabs you'll have to determine which "all"-`checkboxInput` was changed by the user and only refer to the according `checkboxGroupInput`. This could e.g. be done with an `observeEvent()` for every "all"-`checkboxInput`.

Comment: Thanks - I would like to have it so that you can "select all" and "deselect all" on every individual tab Panel - Although this could prove long winded if there are multiple observeEvents for every single tab -any thoughts?

Comment: yep.. that is the annoying part when working with lists of inputs in an observer. Either you observe every input separately or you keep track of the relevant inputs. Here is an [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930397/get-only-inputids-that-have-changed/52932230#52932230) you might want to adapt.

Comment: Thanks for link - i'm going to try it out for remembering which select all has been pressed - although given that the tab penal numbers may change in future this could be a bit difficult - but  i guess wrapping in a function may help it somewhat!