# R Shiny: Is there a possibility to monitor only a subset of input?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a dynamic Shiny UI that generates a big number of input elements of differend kinds (e.g. weights, comments, ...). The inputIds are concatenated from a prefix and an ID-string (e.g. "weight_ABC", "weight_ABD"). I currently use reactiveValuesToList() to loop over the inputIds in order to find out if, for example, a weight has been changed and which one it is (in this case I am greying out zero-weighted entries). This is working but I was wondering if anyone could maybe point me to a more elegant approach.

Is it possible to organize the inputs in a reactiveValues object other than "input$" so that I don't have to include comments and other stuff when I know I am looking for updated weights? Or is there a possibility to directly get the inputId of the input that has been changed.

Once the app starts up and generates the UI the inputIds remain constant. However, I do not know the inputIds in advance as they depend on the input dataset. So "hardcoding" the inputIds is not an option.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930397/get-only-inputids-that-have-changed/52932230#52932230)

Comment: @ismirsehregal This is helpful. Many thanks! I only think, there might be a typo in your example code. The comparison should be "!=" instead of "==", right?.

Comment: You are right. Updated my answer accordingly.